# Could not find or load main class 2.2.1 Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

Using Android Studio 1.0.2, and you are forced to use Gradle 2.2.1. I am trying to import kickflip.io android example (https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example).

I am seeing this error:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at     http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class 2.2.1
```

Gradle Wrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Top-level build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'io.kickflip:sdk:1.1.1'
}
```

My error report is extremely long, so won't post it since the formatting gets corrupted when I copy and paste it in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It feels like you have a corrupt local Gradle installation. If you have not done so already, close Android Studio, delete (or rename) the `.gradle/` directory from the project, and then reopen Studio, to force it to grab a fresh copy.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not working, same error. I double checked my gradle system variables (GRADLE_HOME,Path) which point to:     C:\Gradle\gradle-2.2.1. Any other ideas?

Comment: OK, so you're using a standalone copy of Gradle. Using a command prompt, go into the project directory and try running some Gradle commands directly (e.g., **`gradle tasks`**, **`gradle assembleDebug`**). Do any work?

Comment: @CommonsWare Holy cow, just had to deal with java 7 and java 8 JDK/JRE 64/86 bit issues all last night. Working with java 8 JDK/JRE now. Gradle works fine; new error is `Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()`. I switched `runProguard false` to `minifyEnabled false`, doesn't resolve this new version of AS 1.0.2.

Comment: "Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()" -- you are missing the Gradle for Android plugin. Make sure that you still have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` in your `buildscript` `dependencies` closure.